# Django: Peer authentication failed for user

Tags: django, postgresql, django-settings, django-2.2

I've already a functioning website that use sqlite3 but I prefer to restart my website project with an empty project that immediately use PostgreSQL/PostGIS. At the end of the configuration of `settings.py` I will make a dump for upload all the sqlite3 tables into the new DB. Nobody models of the old project will modify into this new project. The differece between the old and the new project is only the DBMS.

This is **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.contrib.gis',
]
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'my_project_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_of_db_user',
    }
}
```

After this I've tried to test the server with `python3 manage.py runserver` but I see this error message:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed
>   for user "db_user"

I'm sure that *NAME*, *USER* and *PASSWORD* are correct, the db is in localhost. I've created, a couple of week ago, another simple project to learn GeoDjango with this same settings and that website run fine.

Comment: Did you create a new postgres db after changing your config?

Comment: Yes, I've used both command line and PgAdmin4 for do this. Inside my local server there are three db: this db, the default db and the db with which I'm learning GeoDjango.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `host` field in your config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'my_project_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_of_db_user',
        'HOST': 'localhost' # missing part
    }
}
```